# Header Message in Flat File Destination

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to load data from source table to Flat file detination(txt). For example i have employee table with `eid, ename, salary` as column names.

I want to load those columns data into Flat file destination(txt) as test(eid), test(ename),test(salary)..

Ie.., output format has to be like this in my destination(txt)

```
test(1),test(satish),test(20000)  
test(2),test(ram),test(30000)
test(3),test(rahul),test(40000)
```

Comment: What language are you wanting to do this in? edit - I see the c# tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Derived Column transformation for example.

Create a Data Flow task as shown in the first picture.

[image: Sample Data Flow task]

In Derived Column transformation settings you should convert your columns in the format you want to output. Don't forget to cast your non-string columns.

[image: Settings for Derived Column Transformation]

In Flat File Destination delete all the unnesccessary columns (`eid, ename, salary`). Only output columns will redirected to the file.

[image: Flat File Destination columns settings]

And here's your desired output.

[image: CSV output]

Answer (score 0):

Get the data into a DataTable.  Create a StreamWriter.  Loop through the DataTable, parsing your columns into the desired format, and write the line using the StreamWriter.

psuedo-code:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\myfile.txt", false);

foreach(datarow row in datatable.rows)
{
//format the line
writer.Write(myLine);
writer.Write(writer.NewLine);
}
```